# Where do you place event methods that are exclusively related to a derived class, but which call methods not exclusively related to the derived class?

Tags: c#, winforms, inheritance, scope

The original version of the UI of my `WinForms` app included a standard `TreeView`. As such, I placed the methods used to create the `TreeView` nodes and the methods for handling `TreeNode` events in the main form class.

Since then, I've created a class `MyTreeView` that derives from the `TreeView` class (`class MyTreeView : TreeView`) so I can encapsulate custom properties that I need to manage the state of a `MyTreeView` object. I began moving all my `TreeView` and `TreeNode` related code (including event-handlers) into `MyTreeView`. For example, I moved this code from the main form class into  a `MyTreeView` method:

```
ToolStripMenuItem toolStripMenuItem = new ToolStripMenuItem(text: "foo", image: null, onClick: OnClickMethod)
{
    CheckOnClick = true
};
```

It was then I realized `OnClickMethod` did not exist in `MyTreeView` because I originally coded it in the main form class. I went to move `OnClickMethod` from the main form class into `MyTreeView`, but realized that `OnClickMethod` calls other methods that do work related to other main form elements (not just the treeview).

Should I figure out a way to pass the name of `OnClickMethod` from the main form class into the `MyTreeView` method (is this even possible)?

Should I figure out a way to pass an instance of the main form into `MyTreeView` so I can access the event handlers that are resident in the main form class?

Is my overall approach just bad?

How would you handle this scenario?

Comment: Can't you override `OnClickMethod` in some way, and then raise another event that your form can handle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ed Plunkett definitely got me into the ballpark, but I'm answering my own question because I wasn’t able to understand all of what he was trying to teach me without further research. Ed’s instruction gave me the info I needed to figure out the topic I needed to research (thanks, Ed).

I believe Ed’s intent was to have me implement the [.NET Framework technique for handling and raising events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/events/). It’s based on the `delegate model` which follows the `observer design pattern`. The code below shows how I answered my question using this technique. A click on a `TreeNode` `ContextMenuStrip` item) is modeled. I'll use the same technique for other events that occur on the `TreeView`

In short, the requirement is to encapsulate all the code required to create, load, and handle events for a `TreeView` in a derived `MyTreeView` class while informing the main form class of events occurring in a `MyTreeView` object so the main form class can do the non-TreeView things it needs to do as a result of the user interacting with the `MyTreeView` object.

** Main Form Class*

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MyTreeViewDemo
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            //Load the tree view
            myTreeView1.Load();

            //Subscribe to the MyTreeView ContextMenuItemClicked event. 
            // Set it to invoke MyTreeView1_FooClicked when the event is raised
            myTreeView1.ContextMenuItemClicked += MyTreeView1_FooClicked;
        }

        void MyTreeView1_FooClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Do form stuff (other than treeview stuff) that needs to be done when a treenode context menu item is clicked
        }
    }
}
```

** MyTreeView Class **

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MyTreeViewDemo
{
    class MyTreeView : TreeView
    {
        public MyTreeView()
        {
            //This event handler does nothing more than select the node the user clicked
            this.NodeMouseClick += TreeViewTableList_NodeMouseClick;
        }

        // Associate a delegate with an event by including the delegate type in the event declaration
        // Declare an event named ContextMenuItemClicked. 
        // The event is associated with the EventHandler delegate and raised in a method named OnContextMenuItemClicked. 
        public event EventHandler ContextMenuItemClicked;

        /// <summary>
        /// When the user clicks on a treenode context menu item, this method is invoked
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        protected virtual void OnContextMenuItemClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Do treeview stuff that needs to be done when a treenode context menu item is clicked

            //if EventHandler ContextMenuItemClicked is not null, invoke it so that subscribers are notified.
            ContextMenuItemClicked?.Invoke(sender, e);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Method to build a minimum treeview with one node
        /// </summary>
        public void Load()
        {
            TreeNode treeNodeRoot = new TreeNode("tree node item");

            this.Nodes.Add(treeNodeRoot);

            // Create a ContextMenuStrip for the tree node
            ContextMenuStrip contextMenuStripRootNode = new ContextMenuStrip
            {
                ShowCheckMargin = true,
                ShowImageMargin = false
            };

            //Create a menu item for the context menu. Set it to invoke OnContextMenuItemClicked when its clicked
            ToolStripMenuItem menuItem = new ToolStripMenuItem("foo", null, onClick: OnContextMenuItemClicked)
            {
                CheckOnClick = true
            };

            //Add the menu item to the contextstrip.
            contextMenuStripRootNode.Items.Add(menuItem);

            //Set the tree node's ContextMenuStrip property to the ContextMenuStrip.
            treeNodeRoot.ContextMenuStrip = contextMenuStripRootNode;
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///  Select the node the user clicked so that the treeview visually looks as the user expects
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private void TreeViewTableList_NodeMouseClick(object sender, TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e)
        {
            TreeView t = (TreeView)sender;
            //Force the node that was clicked to be selected
            t.SelectedNode = t.GetNodeAt(e.X, e.Y);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The usual pattern for that kind of thing is for `MyTreeView` to have an event `FooClicked`.

This is because the stuff that happens when `foo` is clicked is entirely outside the area of concern of `MyTreeView`. It's `Form1`'s problem, so let `Form1` deal with it. Just raise the event and let the form add a handler for it. `OnClickMethod` will still be defined in `Form1`.

Menu item creation

```
ToolStripMenuItem toolStripMenuItem = 
    new ToolStripMenuItem(text: "foo", image: null, onClick: (s, e2) => OnFooClicked())
{
    CheckOnClick = true
};
```

`(s, e2) => OnFooClicked()` is an event handler that calls `OnFooClicked()`. If that syntax is so bizarre that it's getting in your way, let me know and I'll rewrite it so as to avoid the confusion.

Event definition in MyTreeView:

```
public event EventHandler FooClicked;

protected void OnFooClicked()
{
    //  C#7. If this fails to compile with some weird error let me know and I'll 
    //  provide a backwards compatible version. 
    FooClicked?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

Now in Form1, just wire up an event handler for `myTreeView1.FooClicked`:

```
void myTreeView1_FooClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //  OnClickMethod() is no longer an event handler. It's just a protected 
    //  method that does stuff. I'm 99% sure its sender and e parameters were 
    //  never used. Writing all your logic directly in event handlers is bad 
    //  practice because it leads to weird noise in the code and bizarre, 
    //  inappropriate method names. 
    OnClickMethod();
}
```

As I understand it, this is the requirement:

1. User clicks `toolStripMenuItem1`
2. Form1 hears about that and does something in response.

In the past, Form1 directly created `toolStripMenuItem`, so it directly provided a click handler to the menu item itself.

Now, Form1 does not create `toolStripMenuItem`, so it can't provide the handler. But all Form1 cares about is being notified when somebody clicks that menu item. So we can do that by creating a new event that belongs to MyTreeView. Now, when `toolStripMenuItem` is clicked, its click event is still raised, but the new handler for that click event raises *another* event, an event that Form1 has access to. So Form1 handles that different event instead. That different event is raised in response to the same user action as before: The menu item being clicked.

The only thing missing is for you to add a handler to the event raised by `myTreeView1` in your form. That's done in the control Properties pane in the Visual Studio form designer. There's an Events tab. There's nothing magic or special or secret about this. It's an event like any other event. Just a regular event.

Comment: (Forgive my notation if its squirrelly) Just to be sure: So, there is the event handler  `Form1.myTreeView1_FooClicked(....)` that calls `Form1.OnClickMethod();`. Then, there is event handler `MyTreeView.OnFooClicked()` that calls `MyTreeView.FooClicked(...)`. Question: I assume `Form1.OnClickMethod()` needs to explicitly invoke `MyTreeView.OnFooClicked()`. How do I do that? Otherwise, what's the connection?

Comment: @NovaSysEng See update for clarification about what's an event handler and what isn't. `OnFooClicked()` just raises an event, it's now called *from* a handler. As for *"I assume Form1.OnClickMethod(); needs to explicitly invoke MyTreeView.OnFooClicked()"*, that sentence is utterly mystifying to me. Usually, the user clicks a menu item which causes something to happen. Are you saying that the form is responsible for clicking the menu item? In response to what? All the menu item does is indirectly call `Form1.OnClickMethod()`. If Form1 wants to call that method, just call it.

Comment: Sorry, I had my cause and event mixed up (i.e., which is invoked as a result of the user click and so on.....). Looking this over .....

Comment: In the context of your code, how do I `wire up an event handler for myTreeView1.FooClicked:`? To me, this means `associate a method with an event.`  What event? I mean, MyTreeView.OnFooClicked consumes the right mouse click on the context menu item (i.e., the ToolStripMenuItem), so then what?  I guess I don't understand what the combination of `public event EventHandler FooClicked;` and `FooClicked?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);` does. I think I'm supposed to associate `Form1.myTreeView1_FooClicked()` with `FooClicked` but I don't know how.

Comment: `public event EventHandler FooClicked;` defines an event. `FooClicked?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);` raises the event. "Raising an event" calls any handlers on the event. Have you handled an event? Yes. You have. In your code in your question, you handle an event. Try my code. Put in some breakpoints if you're confused about what it's doing.

Comment: Are you adding an instance of `MyTreeView` to your form? If not, add one. Then set up the event handler for `FooClicked` in the form designer in exactly the same way you set up *any* event handler on *any* control. Do you know how to find the Events tab in the Properties pane in the Visual Studio form designer?

Comment: Yup - I implemented your code and the debugger is on it. I put breakpoints at `FooClicked?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);` (inside MyTreeView.OnFooClicked) and at the call to `OnClickMethod` (inside Form1.myTreeView1_FooClicked(...)). I pause at `FooClicked?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);`, click F10, then, nothing. I presume I should be at the call to `OnClickMethod` (inside Form1.myTreeView1_FooClicked(...)), correct?

Comment: @NovaSysEng Sorry, I can't explain this any better than I already have.